# Python Pyserial Asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyserial

I'm using in my python script the pyserial-asyncio lib. I encountered that from writing to reading it takes around 1s which is in my opinion far to long. Should be some ms only. Does anybody also have this seen or any idea?

Comment: In order for us to help you figure out why your code takes so long, please edit the question to include details, especially code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
import serial_asyncio
import time

class Output(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        global start
        self.transport = transport
        print('port opened', transport)
        cmd = b'config A'
        print("write cmd: " + str(cmd))
        start = time.time()
        transport.write(cmd)  # Write serial data via transport


    def data_received(self, data):
        print('data received', repr(data))
        end = time.time()
        print("write-receive: {0:0.3f}".format(end - start))
        if b'\n' in data:
            self.transport.close()

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print('port closed')
        self.transport.loop.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = serial_asyncio.create_serial_connection(loop, Output, port, baudrate=921600)
    loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
```